# youtube.subscriptions.list (api v3) - nextPageToken isn't available

Tags: java, javascript, api, youtube, subscriptions

I'm trying to get all channels from my subscriptions. But the "nextPageToken" isn't available.

The response should containing "nextPageToken":

(from developers.google.com - YouTube (v3) - Subscriptions: list)

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#subscriptionListResponse",
  "etag": etag,
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "prevPageToken": string,
  "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": integer,
  "resultsPerPage": integer
  },
  "items": [
    subscription Resource
  ]
}
```

**This is my request:**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&maxResults=10&mine=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

**APIs Explorer - YouTube (v3) - Subscriptions.list:**

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.subscriptions.list?part=snippet&maxResults=10&mine=true

**My response:**

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#subscriptionListResponse",
 "etag": "\"XXXXX/XXXXX\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 115,
  "resultsPerPage": 10
 },
 "items": [
  ...
```

Can you tell me why the nextPageToken is missing, please?

Comment: It seems to be working again, however, it is restricted to 500 items: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4282#c6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a JS snippet I came up with to generate pageTokens up to at least 1024, I cannot guarantee that it will produce anything valid beyond that as i could not find any service which will get me tokens for offsets > 450 to validate my guesses and assumptions.

```js
var d0 = "AEIMQUYcgkosw048";
var d1 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
var d2 = d1;
var d1c = 0;
var d2c = 0;
var overflowSuffix = "Q";
var direction = "AA";
var d2OverflowCounter = 0;
var pageSize = 50;

for (i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
  if (i % pageSize == 0) console.log("C" + d1.charAt((d1c / d0.length) % d1.length) + d0.charAt(i % d0.length) + overflowSuffix + direction, ":", i);
  if (++d1c % (1 << 8) == 0) d1c = 1 << 7;
  if (++d2c % (1 << 7) == 0) overflowSuffix = d2.charAt(++d2OverflowCounter) + "E";
}
```

(check developer tools / console to see generated codes)

Answer (score 7):

I have now a workaround for this.
Please tell me if that helps.

The tokens seems to be the same for each page of other API Youtube V3 API calls, so I can use it to fetch all pages of subscriptions I need.

```
tokens = ['CDIQAA','CGQQAA','CJYBEAA','CMgBEAA','CPoBEAA','CKwCEAA','CN4CEAA','CJADEAA','CMIDEAA','CPQDEAA','CKYEEAA', ...]
```

You can use ANOTHER Youtube API to get more page tokens if you need more. Just fetch 1 element a time and log the tokens to use in this API.

I just need to known when to stop... so I checked when API calls returned no channels!

```
@retry(stop_max_attempt_number=7)    
def get_subscription_page(self, channel_id, pageToken):        
    print 'Retrieving subscription page using Youtube API (token: %s)' % pageToken
    res = self.youtube_data_api.subscriptions().list(part="id,snippet,contentDetails",channelId=channel_id, maxResults=50, pageToken=pageToken).execute()
    return res


def get_subscriptions(self, channel_id):
    self.authorize(channel_id)                       
    subs = []         

    # Tokens to deal with api bug...
    # https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7163
    tokens = ['CDIQAA','CGQQAA','CJYBEAA','CMgBEAA','CPoBEAA','CKwCEAA','CN4CEAA','CJADEAA','CMIDEAA','CPQDEAA','CKYEEAA']

    iPage = 0
    pageToken = ''        
    while True:            

        res = self.get_subscription_page(channel_id, pageToken)            

        channelIds = []
        for channel in res['items']: channelIds.append(channel.get('snippet').get('resourceId').get('channelId'))
        pageToken = res.get('nextPageToken')

        # If no next page token is returned... it might be caused by a bug.
        # This workaroud will only have effect when the bug still lives.
        if not pageToken:
            if not channelIds:
                # Workaroud for this: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7163
                print ' (Workaround due to API bug) No channels returned in this API call! Finished!'
                break
            else:
                pageToken = tokens[iPage]

        # get channel info for each channel ID
        channelsInfo = self.get_channel_info(channelIds)            
        subs += channelsInfo
        print ' Itens already retrieved: %d ' % len(subs)                                                            
        iPage += 1

        if args.debug: break
        if pageToken: continue

        print 'No more pages to retrieve!'
        break                

    return subs
```

Comment: its probably better to use the pageInfo.totalresults and look if you got as many items, but thank you for the static tokens!

Comment: The problem of using pageInfo.totalresults is that sometimes the number of items actually returned is different from pageInfo.totalresults. When I run the code above here the pageInfo.totalresults is 236 but some pages returns 49 or 48 itens and in I ended up with 232 itens in total. So... I really must check when no more itens are returned. :)

Comment: One warning, tokens depend on maxResults setting. I got completely different tokens when I set maxResults to 1 and when it was on 50.

Comment: You're right! These tokens I used are for 50 results.

Answer (score 3):

I have a script that runs each hour based on this Youtube API V3 and it stopped to work 4 hours ago. The nextPageToken is not available anymore. Before, it was available exactly like in the first code you posted.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So it seems that's a YouTube-Server error?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I believe so. I'll wait some time to see if they fix it... as there is not I can do on my own.

Comment: pretty much the same here, suddenly nextpagetoken didnt get delivered and i was going mental >< lets hope google fixes this soon. is there a workaround in the meantime?

Comment: It's youtube api bug. You can go here https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7163 and "star it" so it gets more attention