# Why is nextPageToken not showing up for Subscriptions: list?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm using the java-script youtube api and I noticed the nextPageToken is no longer being returned with the Subscriptions: list call. Does anyone know if something changed in the api or is this a bug?

I have the mySubscribers param set to true.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=subscriberSnippet&maxResults=10&mySubscribers=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: I believe this is a bug... as you can see here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30263293/youtube-subscriptions-list-api-v3-nextpagetoken-isnt-available

Comment: I did some code to circumvent that while it is not fixed.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30263293/youtube-subscriptions-list-api-v3-nextpagetoken-isnt-available/30263572#30263572

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's youtube api bug. You can go here https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7163 and "star it" so it gets more attention

Answer (score 0):

You can use Channel: List - and use the mySubscribers function.  It endlessly gives you the nextPageToken.  https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list .  I was also looking on various posts for this solution and no one has put it up, so I am putting it here for others to see.