# Youtube Data Subscription API V3 not returning NextPage when submitted with mySubscribers

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am not getting "nextPageToken" in the response object when I tried to retrieve list of users who subscribed to our channels using YT Data API (v3) Subscription. For some reason YT not returning  "nextPageToken" even though below channel has more than 100K subscribers so could you please advise me on how to be able to fetch next pages of subscribers. Same behavior happening when I tried with any of channels from our CMS account:

Request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?onBehalfOfContentOwner=xxxx&onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel=xxxxxxxxxxx&fields=items(contentDetails,id,snippet(publishedAt,channelId),subscriberSnippet(title,description)),nextPageToken,pageInfo,tokenPagination&maxResults=50&mySubscribers=true&part=id,snippet,contentDetails,subscriberSnippet&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Here is sample response snippet (I trimmed out other 48 items from below list and intentionally masked out subscriber details)

```json
{
    "items": [
        {
            "snippet": {
                "channelId": "UCUR8UieACc2QXl7waH821hQ",
                "publishedAt": "2014-05-20T19:50:44.000Z"
            },
            "contentDetails": {
                "newItemCount": 0,
                "activityType": "all",
                "totalItemCount": 51
            },
            "subscriberSnippet": {
                "description": "",
                "title": "Sebastian Brentsworth"
            },
            "id": "MVPSEm5kMooIHMvcBKqbtFJAp1dHw0GeHza2Iq5KXP"
        },
        {
            "snippet": {
                "channelId": "UCYs04YSyy1soNzyvsDljYVg",
                "publishedAt": "2014-05-28T22:39:30.000Z"
            },
            "contentDetails": {
                "newItemCount": 0,
                "activityType": "all",
                "totalItemCount": 51
            },
            "subscriberSnippet": {
                "description": "",
                "title": "Jason Chan"
            },
            "id": "Xd7_fS3FIA4rnSu6NXEfxF8trXzL8-LspvIuYtDMmc0"
        }
    ],
    "pageInfo": {
        "resultsPerPage": 50,
        "totalResults": 144403
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Known" (Hopefully also to Google) bug:

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7163 and [youtube.subscriptions.list (api v3) - nextPageToken isn't available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30263293/youtube-subscriptions-list-api-v3-nextpagetoken-isnt-available)

For the time being, I've came up with a token generator as a workaround (see other SO post, or here: https://gist.github.com/pulsar256/f5621e85ef50711adc6f)