# Youtube Data API search not returning all results

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to list all videos from a given channel. For whatever reason, no matter how I query youtube data API, I don't get all results.

I use the following query:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=**KEY**&publishedBefore=2018-03-20T08%3A29%3A34Z&publishedAfter=2018-02-20T08%3A29%3A34Z&part=id&channelId=UCPsrtYcqoWEE8-8A2CX241w

And I get only 29 results for all pages (even though total results is 147). The happens for most of other periods.

I checked quota, but it seems everything is fine:

[image]

Any idea what might be wrong? Is there a more reliable way to list all videos for a given channel?

Comment: Can you try modifying your filter if it alters results?

Comment: @noogui - doesn't help. I removed all filters except for dates and channel and I still the fewer results than I would expect. I checked different channels and still the same.

Comment: Just read from [search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) that "The total number of results in the result set.Please note that the value is an approximation and may not represent an exact value. In addition, the maximum value is 1,000,000."
Why not try doing something like create a filter that you know will return the exact amount of your videos ( e.g. 5 videos related to "cats" in your own channel) then execute that search. If it returns 5, then totalResults is irrelevant. If it fails, time to open an issue tracker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround in this question:

[YouTube API returning wrong result counts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31140083/youtube-api-returning-wrong-result-counts)

**tl;dr**: I used "uploads" playlist and playlistItems endpoint to retrieve all videos.