# Youtube Search:list getting PageInfo and nextPageToken null

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-channels

I am trying to get videos from YouTube using keyword. I am using YouTube API Java library. 
I can get first 50 records successfully, but to fetch next records its required to set **nextPageToken**. But i am getting nextPageToken `null`. Below is my code.

```
YouTube.Search.List search = youtube.search().list("id,snippet");
search.setOauthToken(credential.getAccessToken());
search.setMaxResults(50L);
search.setQ(keywords); // keywords is string type and input by user.
search.setType("video");
search.setFields("items(id/kind,id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/thumbnails/default/url)");

VideoList returnList = new VideoList();

    do {

        search.setKey("MYKEY");
        SearchListResponse searchResponse = search.execute();
        // This get 50 items proper.
        List<SearchResult> searchResultList = searchResponse.getItems();


        // Why PageInfo is null? 
        PageInfo pageInfo = searchResponse.getPageInfo();

        // int totalResults = pageInfo.getTotalResults();
        // int pageSize = pageInfo.getResultsPerPage();

        if(searchResponse != null){
            // i use searchResultList and update my database for search.
            ....
            ....

            // PageToken also null.
            String pageToken  = searchResponse.getNextPageToken();
            search.setPageToken(pageToken);
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    } while (true);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I have already studied [email list](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7163) .

Comment: I also tried with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30263293/youtube-subscriptions-list-api-v3-nextpagetoken-isnt-available/30263572#30263572) solution. but many times i got invalid page token exception message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting null because you didnt mention nextpagetoken or pageinfo fields, 
search result set is limited when you set fields explicitly.

```
search.setFields("items(kind,id/kind,id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/thumbnails/default/url),nextPageToken,pageInfo,prevPageToken");

System.out.println("PAGE INFO: " +response.getPageInfo());

System.out.println("next page token :" +response.getNextPageToken());

System.out.println("prev page token:"+ response.getPrevPageToken());
```

Output :
Enter the search term

poker face

PAGE INFO: {"resultsPerPage":2,"totalResults":667891}

next page token :CAIQAA

prev page token:null

Comment: response.getNextPageToken() returns token also for the same first 50 pages